# Theano switch row-wise efficiently

Tags: performance, theano, boolean-logic

I have the following code

```
output = T.switch(cond, a, b)
```

where `cond` is a `(N,1)` bool Tensor, while `a` and `b` are `(N, M)` numeric Tensors with `M` being quite large. The condition operates on a row-wise manner.

I can easily make the switch work by running `T.repeat()` on `cond`, but this is quite slow. Is there a way I can efficiently make the bools in `cond` decide whether `a` or `b` should be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can efficiently make the bools in cond decide whether a or b should be returned?

Yes, you could do

```
cond * a + (1-cond) * b
```

`cond` will be broadcast to `(N, M)` shape.

This should be close to the theoretical limit, which is the memory bandwidth: this operation needs to read about `N*M` elements and write `N*M`.

Instead, we read `2*N*M`, but remove the conditional logic.

(I don't have Theano in front of me, so I am not sure if it's faster than `T.switch`, but it should be about as good as it gets. Also, I'd try casting `cond` to the same `dtype` as `a` and `b`)

---

If you want to update `a` in-place, you can do it using `T.set_subtensor`:

```
a = np.random.uniform(size=(N, M)).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.uniform(size=(N, M)).astype(np.float32)

a = theano.shared(a)
b = theano.shared(b)

c = T.vector() # mostly 0, presumably (1-cond)

nz = T.nonzero(c)

s = T.set_subtensor(a[nz], b[nz])
fn = theano.function([c], [], updates=[(a, s)])

...

fn(1-cond)
```

It may or may not be faster than the first approach, depending on `N`, `M` and other factors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out! Interesting thoughts about the theoretical limit. I guess I could avoid the large reads and writes by exploiting that most often `a` would be the right value to return and it's fine for the method to modify `a` directly. Suppose only 5% of the time `b` should be returned for a given row, couldn't one obtain better performance by modifying `a` directly only on the rows needing modification?

Comment: @pir Are you optimizing for CPU or GPU? What are the typical N, N and dtype?

Comment: @pir also, is this part of a NN or something that needs the gradient?

Comment: Good questions! I'm optimizing for GPU and I do not need the gradient.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that N = 320, M = 10K and dtype = int32.